# Error Query SQL: SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, sql, jpa

tengo problemas con el siguiente @Query, al que no encuentro razon de error: `SQLGrammarException`

```
     @Query("select distinct e.issue.company from CreditLinesAmendmentEntity 
e where " + "(e.issue.ownerBank!=null and (e.issue.ownerBank = ?1)) and " +
        "(UPPER(e.issue.company.name) like ?2 OR UPPER(e.issue.company.companyid) like ?2) AND " +
        "e.issue.status IN ?3 and " +
        "(e.creationDate!=null  and ( e.creationDate >= ?4 and e.creationDate <= ?5 )) AND " +
        "(e.transactionVersion = (SELECT MAX(ee.transactionVersion) FROM 
    CreditLinesAmendmentEntity ee WHERE ee.transactionId=e.transactionId))")
           Page<Company> 
    findBeneficiariesByBeneficiaryBankAndStatusAndCreationDate(Bank beneficiaryBank, 
    String search, List<Status> statuses, Date earliestDate, Date now, Pageable 
    page);
```